# How to fix the accident format with line number with Sphinx v4.5.0?

Tags: format, python-sphinx

Originally, my codes in Sphinx v3.5.4 are quite well. I used the following codes.

```html
.. code-block:: python
    :caption: ex2.py: step 3
    :name: ex2.py
    :linenos:
    :lineno-start: 1
    :emphasize-lines: 2-5

    def Sum(iN):
        if (iN == 0):
            return(0)
        else:
            return(iN + Sum(iN - 1))

    iMax = 10
    for i in range(1, iMax):
        print(i, ':', Sum(i))
```

Then, the Sphinx will output normally as shown as below.

```html
1 def Sum(iN):
2    if (iN == 0):
3        return(0)
4    else:
5        return(iN + Sum(iN - 1))
6 
7 iMax = 10
8 for i in range(1, iMax):
9     print(i, ':', Sum(i))
```

However, after rendered from the Sphinx v4.5.0, my example code is shown as below.

```html
1 def Sum(iN):
2 
    if (iN == 0):
3 
        return(0)
4 
    else:
5 
        return(iN + Sum(iN - 1))
6 
7 iMax = 10
8 for i in range(1, iMax):
9     print(i, ':', Sum(i))
```

Basically, I remove the :lineno: parameter, the accident line-break condition is disappear. Anyway, it might be come with line-number feature. Is there anyone has any solution to solve this problem?

Note that I used the following required modules in my environment.

```
sphinx==4.5.0
graphviz==0.19.1
sphinxcontrib-plantuml==0.23
sphinxcontrib-blockdiag==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-actdiag==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-nwdiag==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-seqdiag==2.0.0
sphinxbootstrap4theme>=0.6.0
sphinxcontrib.bibtex==2.4.2
sphinxcontrib.httpdomain==1.8.0
sphinx-autorun==1.1.1
sphinx-copybutton==0.5.0
hieroglyph==2.1.0
```

Comment: So the problem is that there are extra blank lines in the output? I cannot reproduce this with Sphinx 4.5.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I pulled back and used the v3.5.4. Then it work fine now. Haha... I believe that it might be affected by one of the extension plugins.

Comment: Yes, I fianlly found the bug in the Sphinx v4.5.0. That is, the accident break will be occurred when I use the :emphasize-lines: option in the .. code-block:: or .. literalinclude:: directives. All of the :emphasized-lines: will be added one more line break between the lineno and code. Any solution to avoid it and also use :emphasized-lines: option?

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same issue. This [github issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/10204) says the bug was caused by v2.3.1 of the `pygments` package and is fixed in v2.11.2 of `pygments`.